# Is it possible to use javascript to resize everything on the viewport to a percentage of it's original height and width on event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I'm new to JavaScript but I got at least a basic idea of it. I wanna optimize my personal site for mobile. Everything regarding screen orientation and element positioning is done. They all center very nicely and the layout is just as planned. But I have a problem that for some reason, when viewed on mobile, every element is too large to the point I have to scroll horizontally to see the rest of the page. I can't zoom out on mobile view either, so I have to resort to switching it to desktop view to see the site properly.

I've actually tried searching all over for some way to do this but every result just amounts to detecting a viewport size but not resizing the viewport or every element itself. Also all the elements have their positioning set to relative using the top, bottom, left and right properties, every element on my site does not have a parent div, they're all parented to the body. I also have to mention, I want to avoid using media queries for this one because the host I'm using seems to take issue with it. I'm still not sure what specific percentage I need to resize it to but I'll figure it out through trial and error. But I'm not sure where to go in terms of it's base code.

This is my code so far, and I'm very satisfied with it's behavior. But I want to know what I should add to achieve what I'm looking for:

```
const advert = document.getElementById('advert');

const about = document.getElementById('about');

const menubox = document.getElementById('menubox');

const musicplayer = document.getElementById('musicplayer');

const toybox = document.getElementById('toybox');

const stamps = document.getElementById('stamps');

const notepad = document.getElementById('notepad');

var check;

window.mobileAndTabletCheck = function() {

  let check = false;

  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

};

if (check = true){

switch (screen.orientation.type) {

  case "landscape-primary":

  case "landscape-secondary":

    advert.style.right = '-145px';

    about.style.left = '319px';

    menubox.style.left = '920px';

    musicplayer.style.right = '-145px';

    toybox.style.left = '462px';

    stamps.style.left = '920px';

    notepad.style.right = '-145px';

    break;

  case "portrait-secondary":

  case "portrait-primary":

    advert.style.right = '5px';

    about.style.left = '169px';

    menubox.style.left = '770px';

    musicplayer.style.right = '5px';

    toybox.style.left = '312px';

    stamps.style.left = '770px';

    notepad.style.right = '5px';

    break;}

}
```

Comment: Can you do this? Yes. *Should* you do this (on devices with lower power components, reduced computing power, lower bandwidth, and probably less memory)? No, almost certainly not. While it's possible, look at media queries, and responsive design (particularly CSS flex, and grid).

Comment: @DavidThomas alright, I'll try separating the elements by ID in separate files and I'll see if that gets it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into solving your problem, let me point out that media queries are CSS rules and all your host would need in order to allow them is to store these rules either as separate CSS files or style tags of your HTML, something that your host most probably allows, as media queries are evaluated and executed inside the browser, the server only provides the files to run. Yet, percentage support does not even require media queries. Here's some good ol' CSS using percentages:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

body > div#main {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

As about doing this with Javascript, you could set up some simple CSS rules, like

```
body #advert {
    right: -145px;
}

body.portrait #advert {
    right: 5px;
}
```

Basically, you have a default of -145 pixel and if body has a portrait class, then the value changes to 5 pixels. So, your switch-case would change to

```
switch (screen.orientation.type) {

  case "landscape-primary":

  case "landscape-secondary":

    document.body.classList.remove("portrait");

    break;

  case "portrait-secondary":

  case "portrait-primary":

    document.body.classList.remove("portrait");

    break;
    
    }
```

Untested, let me know of the result of your tests. Note that I only set a single element's styling.

Finally, if you absolutely can't use CSS for some unintuitive (and unprobable) reason, then you can set JS as you did in your code. If you need to further improve the behavior of your site on mobile view, then you will need to provide further information about what's currently wrong, why it's wrong, how it should look alike instead and it would be great if you could visualize the problem and share some reproducible example.